# RXJS call with takeUntil(OnDestroy) returns cancelled from the post API

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I have added the below rxjs and the first call made is a Post. Once the takeUntil(OnDestroy) is added, the post API returns a cancelled option as below

[image]

[image]

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGdbh.png)

If the takeuntil line is removed the post returns a successfule status - 204.
Why does this problem occur ?

Comment: `takeUntil` should be the last item in a `pipe` chain, also `this.onDestroy`  should be a `Subject` like: `onDestroy = new Subject();`

Comment: what's `OnDestroy` ? a subject ? where are you nexting it ?

Comment: @robert I tried adding takeUntil within the pipe after the last switchMap or after the map , still I get the same error

Comment: @Stavm yes its a subject and unsubscribed within ngOnDestroy     



ngOnDestroy() {
  this.onDestroy.next();
  this.onDestroy.complete();
}

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend you this code to apply  unsubscription :

```
@Component(...)
export class MyComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private unsubscribe: Subject; // boilerplate
  constructor(private heroService: MyApiService) {}
  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.heroService
      .callSomeServerApi()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe)) // boilerplate
      .subscribe(() => window.location = 'https://another.site`)
  }
  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe.next(); // boilerplate
    this.unsubscribe.complete(); // boilerplate
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Rebai Ahmed, but I've tried the same callSomeServerApi that makes a post API where I get the cancelled response in the status. Using the same boiler plate as well.

Comment: So it doesn't help you?

Comment: No as I mentioned Im getting the cancelled response

Comment: What do you mean by the canceled response? did you not get the result?

Comment: Get a response as in the original question (see screenshot). In the chrome developer tools. I dont get a result. The status response is cancelled instead of a 204 or a 500

Comment: Just check the screenshot, there is a lot of requests are pending so the cancelation it's made by switchMap operator not the takeUnitl